# cant open file in app from email

Tags: iphone

i have managed to get my app to email a copy of its database to my self, but now when i try and re open it, it says "open in my app" but does nothing. This is what i have in my info.plist

```
<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.darcapps.myapp.lb</string>
        <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
        <string>myapp backup</string>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <string>lb</string>
            <key>public.mime-type</key>
            <string>application/myapp</string>
        </dict>
        <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.data</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>myapp backup</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Owner</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.darcapps.myapp.lb</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

The other thing i wasnt sure about was `<string>com.mycompany.myapp.extName</string>`
Do i have to set these anywhere? eg do i have to set a setting anywhere to tell it what my app is called and what my company is?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swapped over to xcode 4 and it made the whole process easier